# How to get SQL AVG() for each foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a bunch of ratings. Each of these ratings has a foreign key called "i_id", linking it to a specific institution.
Of course, there are many ratings, and a lot of them will same the same i_id.
I was wondering if there's any way to use the AVG() SQL function, to get an average of all ratings, for each i_id.

This query is what I have tried:

```
SELECT AVG(rating), i_id FROM `health_rating` WHERE 1
```

But the result I get is a single average of all ratings in the table, regardless of i_id.

[image: This is my table]

[and this is the single result i am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/397f5.png)

Comment: Also the result is wrong.. Why would a AVG have anny relation with i_id you are getting without using a GROUP BY..  In fact your query is ANSI/ISO SQL standards invalid and should error as mentioned in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: ..........what?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your query by `i_id`:

```
SELECT   AVG(rating), i_id 
FROM     `health_rating`
GROUP BY i_id
```

Comment: Fantastic. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

So, you may have to GROUP BY based on i_id. Result of GROUP BY will be apply to AVG function to make it workable.

```
SELECT i_id, AVG(rating) as avg_rating 
FROM `health_rating`
GROUP BY i_id
```